# Unexpected Values In LinkedList Java

Tags: java

I am getting weird return in memory for my linked list. I'm not sure what the cause is... After the code iterates through the database and attempts to put my data into the list... the linked list shows all the elements being the same or better yet it sets all the values to the last record set.

```
public LinkedList<Property> GetProperties()
    {   
        System.out.println("Get Properties...");
        Statement stmt = null;

        LinkedList<Property> properties = new LinkedList<Property>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM PROPERTIES;";
                     System.out.println(strCurrentDBFile);

        ResultSet rs = null;
           try{ 
                  Property prpty = new Property();

                  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + strCurrentDBFile);

                  stmt = conn.createStatement();

                   rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                  while(rs.next()){
                     prpty.strPrptyName = rs.getString(1);
                     prpty.strPrptyAddress1 = rs.getString(2);
                     prpty.strPrptyAddress2 = rs.getString(3);
                     prpty.strPrptyCity = rs.getString(4);
                     prpty.strPrptyState = rs.getString(5);
                     prpty.strPrptyZipCode = rs.getString(6);

                     properties.push(prpty);
                  }

                  rs.close();
                  conn.close();

               }catch(SQLException se){
                  //Handle errors for JDBC
                  se.printStackTrace();
               }catch(Exception e){
                  //Handle errors for Class.forName
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }finally{
                  //finally block used to close resources
                  try{
                     if(stmt!=null)
                        stmt.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se2){
                  }// nothing we can do
                  try{
                     if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                     se.printStackTrace();
                  }//end finally try              

               }//end try

           return properties;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a new instance of `Property` for each record. Currently you've got this

```
Property prpty = new Property();
```

... *outside* the loop, so your linked list consists of many references to the same object. That line should be *inside* the loop, so that you create a new instance, populate it, and then add a reference to it into your linked list.

If that doesn't explain the problem to you clearly enough, I'd suggest revisiting how objects and references work in Java before you go any further.

Additionally, I'd strongly recommend using a try-with-resources statement for your resources, rather than manually closing them.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought it would reassign the value with the new record set.

Comment: @Dorian: Why would it do that? How would it know to create a new instance, without you telling it to do so?

Comment: You are right... it would not have not known. Each element in the list contained the same initial reference to element created before the loop. So when the last value was assigned, each element in the list reflected it.

Comment: I'm clearly rusty... thanks again

Answer (score 4):

it is because all the objects in you list have the same reference, change :

```
while(rs.next()){
    prpty.strPrptyName = rs.getString(1);
    prpty.strPrptyAddress1 = rs.getString(2);
    prpty.strPrptyAddress2 = rs.getString(3);
    prpty.strPrptyCity = rs.getString(4);
    prpty.strPrptyState = rs.getString(5);
    prpty.strPrptyZipCode = rs.getString(6);

    properties.push(prpty);
}
```

to :

```
while(rs.next()){

     Property prpty = new Property();          //create new instance in every iteration.

     prpty.strPrptyName = rs.getString(1);
     prpty.strPrptyAddress1 = rs.getString(2);
     prpty.strPrptyAddress2 = rs.getString(3);
     prpty.strPrptyCity = rs.getString(4);
     prpty.strPrptyState = rs.getString(5);
     prpty.strPrptyZipCode = rs.getString(6);

     properties.push(prpty);
}
```

and that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Put instance of `Property` in while loop.

```
while(rs.next())
{
Property prpty = new Property();
//do your stuff
}
```

**Why?**

Because you are using same object everytime (no new reference) in your while loop, hence you see all the elements as last element in the linked list.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought it would reassign the value with the new record set.

Comment: @Dorian As solution helped you, you can mark the question as answered for benefit of others :)

Comment: Ok... I think I got... I clicked the check mark.... My first time actually posting to stackoverflow

Comment: Nice. Hope next time we needn't point it out :)